# $T(B_E)$ is closed for $T$ a bounded linear map

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:E\rightarrow F$ be a bounded linear map for E and F Banach spaces, and E reflexive. Let $B_E$ be the unitary closed ball in $E$. How would you argue that $T(B_E)$ is closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $E$ is reflexive, its closed unit ball is weakly compact, and $T$, being continuous from the weak topology to the weak topology, takes weakly compact sets to weakly compact sets.

Comment: But how do I connect weakly compact with closed?

Comment: why is $T$ continuous with respect to weak topologies?

Comment: Because the weak topology is the weakest topology that makes every lineal function continuous.

Comment: ... every bounded linear functional, that is.  And if $\varphi$ is a bounded linear functional on $F$, $\varphi \circ T$ is a bounded linear functional on $E$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael you are right my bad

Comment: I'm really sorry but I still don't see how is that weakly compact implies closed.

Comment: Weakly compact implies weakly closed, and weakly closed implies closed.